# Looking for a pure Python method to convert Lat/Long To MGRS

Tags: python, convert, coordinates

Does anyone know of any packages out there that implement a pure python method to convert lat/long coordinates to MGRS coordinates?

PyPi has a package, but it requires some c-extensions from another source, and I didn't want to use that.  I figured before I go an recreate a complicated process, I'm hoping the community can make my life a tad easier.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs) the pypi package you are referring to?

Comment: Yep, this is the pypi package I am talking about.

Comment: The GeoTrans C extensions come bundled in the package and are free to use. Is usage the issue?

Comment: I am also looking for better solution to this problem with C code
I am trying to install the package [PyPi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs#downloads)however, stuck with C lib unavailability on my system Can someone help in solving the problem,
Getting C error with: # python setup.py install `running install running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to mgrs.egg-info/requires.txt
writing mgrs.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to mgrs.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mgrs.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'mgrs.egg-info/SOURCES.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of the PyPI package. You could simply port the GeoTRANS code that lives in this package to Python if you want a pure-Python extension. Do you want to use this on AppEngine or something?  Otherwise, a ctypes wrapper to a C extension that you don't have to worry about at all with pre-compiled versions for Windows is as good as it'll get...

Comment: Howard, Can you post a link to the c-code? Thanks Josh

Comment: Josh, if you pull the .tar.gz file of the PyPI package, the C files are in there to just do the MGRS. Note that there's a lot of trig and other messy math :)

Comment: Thanks Howard. I'll let you know how I do. I can't post a comment I noticed once some person determined this question was answered.